# Groff ignores line breaks from my shell

Tags: pdf, shell, ps

I've been using groff to make ps files for printing with the -man flag. If I want to convert anything else such as a header file or just the output from ls -l or other program the line breaks are ignored, producing a mess. How can I get groff to see and respect the line breaks in use in the shell?

This produces an output but the tabs are messed up:

```
groff -mom hexd.c > out.ps
```

But this messes with both tabs and line breaks:

```
cat hexd.c | groff -mom > out.ps
```

What I would really like is something like this:

```
man -t gdb | open -f -a preview
```

Which opens a perfect post script version of the man page in preview on max os.
BTW. `man -t` is equivalent to:

```
groff  -Tps  -mandoc -c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`groff` is a typesetting language, and it's expecting input in its language, not plain text.  You may be looking for something like `enscript` or `a2ps` (ascii-to-postscript).

Comment: It works for transferring man pages, which is also plain ascii AFAIK, it can also apart from ps also produce html. Anyway what lead to this was the following:

"man -t gdb | open -f -a preview"

Which opens the gdb man page in preview on mac os x.

Comment: This is from the groff man page: "DESCRIPTION
       This document describes the groff program, the main front-end for the groff document formatting system."

Comment: The `groff` source for manpages is not "plain" text.  It's a markup language.  If you feed `groff` something that's not in its markup language, it's not going to look right.  It's not that different conceptually from HTML or LaTeX, which also ignore line breaks in the source.

Here is an example of `groff` source for a manpage:
http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/bin/ls/ls.1?rev=1.100.10.1;content-type=text%2Fplain
If your input to `groff` doesn't look something like that, the ouput probably isn't going to look right.

Comment: Yes, but even plain text have line breaks in place i.e \n, and with the myriad of options for both groff, and family I'm pretty sure it's possible. Also, there is no reason that the two first examples in my first post should look different. There should be no difference in the input that groff recieves. I just put up the second one up there to emulate what I would like to do, print header files on my printer in a decent format.

Comment: Or you could use tools that are designed to do what you want, like those I mentioned.  Whatever.

Comment: True, but it's somewhat more satisfying to use something that is already installed and also more in spirit of using a command line.

Comment: I would say it's more in the spirit of the command line to use the right tool for the job.  
http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/enscript.1.html

Comment: Well, that is different argument entirely. My point was the relation between building something from semantic parts vs getting an app for every problem that needs to be solved. Anyway, what you came up with there is great! Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the low-level `.nf` troff command for "no filling".

E.g.

```
$ ls -l | sed '1i\
.nf\
.fam C' | groff > out.ps
```

The macro packages also have their own commands for code listings, such as `.l` in [-mk](http://ankarstrom.se/%7Ejohn/mk.html).